# How to pass prop to sibling in React?

Tags: responsive-design, reactjs

I've [designed a pretty simple responsive layout](http://codepen.io/ccorcos/pen/jPzNpP) (be sure to open link with Chrome) and now I'm trying to implement it in React. I've attached some screenshots of the layout as well.

This app is supposed to be the typical tab/nav app, but due to the responsive layout, the view hierarchy is pretty awkward to work with in React.

I've built a React component called `Layout` to abstract away all the layout stuff. Layout also has props for `renderLeft`, `renderRight`, `title`, and `onTab`. Layout's children are then rendered into the content block.

The easy solution would be to make Layout a child of the current view and render whatever you want. However, this is going to mess up some animations I had in mind. I want to have a CSSTransitionGroup element wrapped around the tabbar, the title, and the left and right buttons animating them as they change. Thus, **the `Layout` element must remain the same between the views else a new CSSTransitionGroup element will be rendered for each view** which isn't good.

So now the problem is that I have a `Layout` component with a view rendered as its child (but sort of as sibling with respect to the `App` component), but the view needs to specify `renderLeft`, `renderRight` and `title` for the Layout which is its parent! For example, in the top-level `App` component, the render function may look like the following, and I need some way of setting Layout's `renderLeft` from the `View`.

```js
render() {
    return (
        <Layout renderLeft={??}>
          <View setRenderLeft={??}/>
        <Layout/>
    )
}
```

The only thing I've thought of so far seems totally like the wrong way of doing it:

In the top-level `App` component, have a state variables for `renderLeft`, `renderRight`, and `title` and `App` passes those to the `Layout` props. Now for the view, pass some functions like `setRenderLeft`, `setRenderRight`, and `setTitle` which will change the `App` state and thus change the `Layout`. We can thus call these functions in `componentWillMount` for each view.

This just seems like a total hack and seems to break the whole idea of one-directional-data-flow. However, I'm not sure how else to do it! Are there any more proper ways of doing this? I'm reminded of the concept of delegation when building iOS apps, but thats very OOP and not very FP.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little difficult to tell exactly what the issue is, however if I were you I would read up on https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.
>   Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.

You want to either have the siblings talk to the parent and communicate there, or at the global level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is that my layout view needs to get information from its children. I guess I'll have to use some sort of global event system. But that just feels terrible for some reason. Data flow will no longer be one-directional...

Comment: Global event is exactly what FB recommends. I don't think the data goes backwards in the chain, it just gets pushed from the child to the top of the structure, and then flows downward.

Comment: I guess so. Its just more "pure" which is probably why it feels uncomfortable. But it makes sense. I'm not sure how else you could do it...